# Json string with date to Google calendar

Tags: javascript, html, json, google-visualization, google-calendar-api

Lately I have been visualizing information using Google Charts. I have been reading from a text file containing a json string. 
Columns are added manually and then iterating through the json string to populate the rows. So far so good this method is working. But now I have a problem reading a json string that has a date type.

This is my Test.txt file from which I populate the datatable.

```
[
    {"Date":"2014-12-13T00:00:00","Frequency":35},
    {"Date":"2014-12-14T00:00:00","Frequency":24},
    {"Date":"2014-12-15T00:00:00","Frequency":15}
]
```

If I add the dates manually e.g.

```
dataTable.addRows(
    [ new Date(2012, 3, 13), 37032 ],
    [ new Date(2012, 3, 14), 38024 ]
);
```

It works fine therefore the problem is related to the format of the date being read from the string.

This is how rows are populate dynamically...

```
for (var i = 0; i < dataValues.length; i++) {
    data.addRow([dataValues[i].Date, dataValues[i].Frequency]);
    }
```

How can I fix this problem... code example and explanation are appreciated. I guess that somehow i need to change the format from this `2014-12-14T00:00:00` to this `new Date(2012, 3, 14)`

Comment: Have you tried `data.addRow([new Date(dataValues[i].Date), dataValues[i].Frequency]);` ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes I tried same problem.

Comment: You will need to show more of your JSON file and how `dataValues` object comes into existence

Comment: Here it comes this is my Test.txt file from which I populate the datatable. `code`[{Date":"2014-12-13T00:00:00","Frequency":35}, {Date":"2014-12-14T00:00:00","Frequency":24}, {Date":"2014-12-15T00:00:00","Frequency":15}] `code`

Comment: Please edit your question and post this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this one?

```
for (var i = 0; i < dataValues.length; i++) {
var splitted = dataValues[i].Date.split(/[- :T]/);
    dataTable.addRows([new Date(splitted[0], splitted[1]-1, splitted[2], splitted[3], splitted[4], splitted[5]), dataValues[i].Frequency]);
    }
```

Edit:

As Alternative way

```
var rowArray = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < dataValues.length; i++) {
    var splitted = dataValues[i].Date.split(/[- :T]/);
        rowArray.push([new Date(splitted[0], splitted[1]-1, splitted[2], splitted[3], splitted[4], splitted[5]), dataValues[i].Frequency]);
        }
dataTable.addRows(rowArray);
```

Comment: I tried but still same problem. Somehow I need to format the date in the test.txt to new Date(yyyy-mm-dd) i think.

Comment: please write the problem? what is the problem?any js error?

Comment: No errors just a blank screen. However as i already said if I add rows manually like so dataTable.addRows(
    [ new Date(2012, 3, 13), 37032 ],
    [ new Date(2012, 3, 14), 38024 ]
);  the calendar is dislayed.

Comment: Can you try code that is after the Edit text? And is it data.addRow or dataTable.addRows which one do you use?

Comment: I tried, I'm know having the title displayed but not the data. I am using dataTable.addRows. Sorry for that.